# How do I reduce the space between buttons in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

[image]

I am creating a cross platform application using Xamarin Forms, However as you can see on the left the spacing in between my buttons in my android application is too much as I can not seem to reduce it. The buttons are children of a StackLayout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a different spacing on each platform

```
<StackLayout.Spacing>
  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:double" iOS="5" Android="0" WinPhone="10" />
</StackLayout.Spacing>
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot that I could use the OnPlatform Class to set attributes of Layouts and Views. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If accepted solution does not work for you in Xamarin.Forms (Xamarin 4.10), you can also specify the following:

`<StackLayout Padding="20" Spacing="0"> 
    ... 
</StackLayout>`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.